# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ defined by $f(x)=e^{ix}$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof?

> Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ defined by $f(x)=e^{ix}$ is a homomorphism, and determine its kernel and image.

Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{R}^+$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x+y) &=& e^{i(x+y)} \\
&=& e^{ix}e^{iy} \\
&=& f(x)\times f(y)
\end{eqnarray}

Also,
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Im}(f) &=& \{e^{ix}:x \in \mathbb{R}^+\} \\
&=& \{x \in \mathbb{C}: |x|=1\}
\end{eqnarray}

And,
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{ker}(f)&=&\{x \in \mathbb{R}^+:e^{ix}=1\} \\
&=& \{2 \pi n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Is there a specific point you weren't sure about? Your proof looks good to me.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I've thought it was also necessary to check that $f(0) = 1+0i$ but I was wrong.

Comment: Could you please clarify both Groups. I've read it as the set of Real Numbers under it's definition of addition with the set of Complex Numbers under it's definition of multiplication. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean $(\Bbb R,+)$ and $(\Bbb C^\times,\cdot)$; but as written now there is a problem which bothers me, namely $\Bbb R^+$ often denotes the positive elements of $\Bbb R$, and therefore the kernel of $f$ cannot possibly include negative elements such as $-2\pi$.

Other than that, I don't know what theorems you've seen before, but you haven't really proved what the image and kernel are. You just wrote sets. Why is the kernel *exactly* those numbers which have the form $2n\pi$ where $n\in\Bbb Z$? and why is the image of $f$ *exactly* $x\in\Bbb C$ such that $|x|=1$?

(It is correct, though, and it might be that you've seen theorems and exercises before this one, which mitigate the lack of details. I couldn't possibly know.)

Answer (score 1):

This question probably originates from Ex 2.4.6 of the book [Algebra](https://smile.amazon.com/Algebra-Michael-Artin/dp/0130047635) by Michael Artin.  I believe the notation there

> $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$

means

> $f:(\mathbb{R},+) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{C},\times)$

In particular, it *doesn't* mean the domain is limited to only positive real numbers.

Therefore:
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Im}(f) &=& \{e^{ix}:x \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
&=& \{x \in \mathbb{C}\}
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{ker}(f)&=&\{x \in \mathbb{R}:e^{ix}=1\} \\
&=& \{2 \pi n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: That is not the image. The image is the circle of radius 1 in the complex plane.